# How can I sort the files of following program and remove . and .. directories?

Tags: php

```
<?php
  $dir = "/source_directory_name/";
  if (is_dir($dir)){
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
      while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
        echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";
      }
      closedir($dh);
    }
  }
?>
```

I have used `sort($file);` command after the loop, but no result comes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: :)

```
$files = array();
$dir = opendir($dir); 
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
    if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "index.php")) {
            $files[] = $file; // put in array.
    }   
}

natsort($files); // sort.

foreach($files as $file) {
    echo("<a href='$file'>$file</a> <br />\n");
}
```